# Pull down to something

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

In a country song by Blake Shelton "Home sweet home", l came across this construction:

Pull down to a cane bridge.

I looked up most of the dictionaries, but none of them used the phrasal verb ***pull down to***. It seems that the insertion of ***to*** would make it a bit difficult to infer the meaning. My guess is that it means to park the car beside the bridge. Is it correct?
[image]

Comment: Please provide more context. It *could* mean the same as "pull up at" but there's no way to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some think that this is better not analysed as a multi-word verb – contrast intransitive 'pull up' meaning 'come to a halt', which many/most would consider unary. (There are many prepositions/particles (traditionally also considered adverbs) that can slot in after 'pull'.)

Thus [ODE; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pull+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=pull+meaning&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyCQgAEEUYORiABDIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABNIBCTU3NzdqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has:

> **pull** [verb]
>
> ...
>
> 2. move steadily in a specified direction or manner.

That dictionary gives the example

> - *The bus was about to pull away.*

which I'd say looks more like a multi-word verb usage (= depart) to me.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull) also does not include multi-word verbs, but gives what it regards as verb + adverb (with possible transitivising preposition) examples:

> **pull** [verb]
>
> ...   B2 [Intransitive; + adv/prep]: to move in the stated direction:
>
> - pull ahead: *During the last lap of the race one of the runners began to pull ahead.*
> - pull out of: *We waved as the train pulled out of the station.*
> - pull back: *Our armies are pulling back on all fronts.*

The example

- *Pull down to the cane bridge*,

if analysed as simplex verb plus adverb plus PP, obviously uses both adverb and preposition to show both direction and (with the whole prepositional phrase) destination. I'd say 'pull / down /...' is less unary than some other examples. Other related examples I'd certainly class as involving prepositional phrases are:

- *The police launch pulled alongside the yacht*.
- *Pull up to the loading bay*. (though [Farlex considers 'pull up to' unary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+up+to))
- *The train slowly pulled into the station.* (though again [Farlex considers 'pull into' unary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+into))

However analysed, the meaning of *[Pull] [down] to the cane bridge* is clear: *[Move slowly] [downwards] [as far as the cane bridge]*. 'Pull' connotes power, whether laborious or with plenty in reserve.

The use of 'down' after 'pull' is probably rarer than that of other prepositions; note that on the other hand 'pull up to' has the conflicting pull of 'pull up' meaning 'stop'.

Comment: I had to look up *unary*, according to Wikipedia it seems to be exclusive to the field of mathematics. What do you mean by saying the meaning of a phrasal verb (multi-word verb) is less unary? That it can have more than one word (such as a preposition) or interpretation?

Comment: 'Unary' vs 'binary = two-part' etc. Try M-W. // 'Pull up' is a multi-word verb when meaning 'stop' (in a car, for instance). 'Up' does not fulfil prototypical prepositional connection to a NP. Traditionally, it's a particle. As 'pull up' has a single word equivalent, I'd class the two-orthographic-word string as a single lexeme (after Crystal). Compare the open compound 'ink well', spelling variant of 'inkwell'. // I'm saying that some examples are clearly V + PP (drove into the station), some better seen as MWV + object (if transitive) (took off the King) ...

Comment: but that some are not easy to firmly place in either camp (The train slowly pulled into the station ... I disagree with Farlex here, thinking that [pull] [into] is more binary than unary, so not a MWV / 'phrasal verb'.  // CGEL has a totally different analysis, not accepting even open compound nouns.

Comment: Ok... that makes more sense now you've explained it. I still think unary is too esoteric a word for non-linguists, and I'm not convinced it fits well in this particular case. But the idea it represents in your answer is interesting nevertheless.

Comment: I'm not writing for non-linguists. Non-linguists are hardly likely to be enquiring about the single- or multi-lexeme nature of various candidate multi-word verbs. Multi-word verbs, which Claudia Claridge wrote an essential book on (and CGEL reject as non-existent).

Answer (score 2):

The song is in American English, so a few words are different to British English, but they are nearly always understandable for native British speakers

> We take a trip down memory lane
> Dirt on the truck, no chance of rain
> …

The singer and his girlfriend (?) are driving to his hometown in a truck. The truck is covered in road dust/mud/filth (*dirt*)

> Pull down to the cane bridge
> Park in the ditch

They stop at (*[pull up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-up)*) the bridge and park the truck in a ditch.

I searched for a dictionary definition of *pull down*, which would match the sense of the verbal phrase, but it wasn't even listed by the American *Merriam-Webster*. It suggests that the expression is a regionalism or dialect typical of someone from Nashville, Tennessee (Southern United States).

Comment: +1 "*the* ditch" runs along the side of the road, a drainage ditch.  When you're in your car or truck you can "pull over" and "pull up" and down South you can also "pull down".

Comment: Up North we can "swing down".   https://youtu.be/tbRmxsFahzw

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : As you know, a non-native speaker gets confused when he can't find a precise answer for a specific question. Anyway your answer is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sense of *pull* usually implies a short detour or excursion.

> We would like to thank all of our loyal customers here at Gering Garden Center for making this another fantastic season! To show our gratitude have we got sales for you!!! 4pk bedding plants $1.00, Fall blooming Mums $3.00 and beautiful day lily's just $15.00! Hanging baskets and planters are also marked down for a steal! **So pull on down to**  "THE BIG HOUSE" in the back for great savings here at Gering Garden Center!!
> https://www.facebook.com/geringgardencenter/

> A point of importance is that these
> main track absolute leaving signals
> are located opposite the clearance
> point on the turnouts, thus being
> "short" of the switches, so that, for
> example, an eastbound train which is
> to hold the main line for a meet, can,
> with safety, **pull on down** and stop ...
> https://www.jonroma.net/media/signaling/railway-signaling/1944/Canadian%20Pacific%20Installs%20Automatic%20Block%20Signaling.pdf

> If you arrive earlier than 3:25 to pick up 1st-6th graders (and younger siblings) –
> do not park in the driveway while waiting – this backs up the cars into the
> highway. You must **pull on down** and circle back around until the bell rings.
> https://core-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/asset/uploaded_file/1536/Glencoe_PS/3441958/Elementary_Handbook__2023-24.pdf - page 17.

*Pull on down* is a the more common formulation. Shelton may have needed to adjust the phrase for the song. But the shorter version is pretty common as well. (but harder to search for).

> Cars may pull up anywhere long the terminal's outer traffic lane in the circle although we recommend you **pull down to** the far north end of the traffic circle as the curb as you enter is often congested.
> https://www.flyreagan.com/travel-information/meeting-passengers